# event communication between sibling components in angular

Tags: angular

I have  two sibling components in angular. event should bind to other component as well.

I am new here in angular Please help me.

sibling-1 HTML

```
<div [class.close1]="mi_state">
    <a class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" (click)="toggleMenu()" role="button"><span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

sibling-1 TS

```
mi_state = false;
  hm_state = false;
  toggleMenu() {
    if(this.mi_state == false){
      this.mi_state = true;
      this.hm_state = true;
    }else{
      this.mi_state = false;
      this.hm_state = false;
    }
```

sibling-2 HTML

```
<aside [class.hide_menu]="hm_state">
</aside>
```

I have a button in one component and respective classes should toggle on single click. I could get it in same component. Not working in Sibling component.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mulq4z) and your solution is working fine.

I beleive you forgot to add some contents and height/width so you didn't see it reflected.

```
.close1{
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
}

.hide_menu{
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your component has no relation parent-child, but is in scene at time and is in the same `<router-outlet>`, you can use a reference variable (I imagine you has navvar and aside component), else you need use a service, see the docs [communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

```
<navvar #navbarRef><navvar>
<aside [class.hide_menu]="navbarRef.hm_state">
</aside>
```